# Experiencing issue with Classipress (wordpress) home page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a website through Wordpress using Classipress theme. I'm having a weird issue, where the home page I want to display is only displayed when a user is connected. When a user is not, there is a strange "blog" page, which is, I guess, from the home.php file.

Please find below the two situations :

User connected and homepage (the one i always want):

[image]

The homepage i get when not connected :

[image]

Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's asking this question i solved it by deleting the home.php file.